# Random Test Crash TDD Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, tdd, mockk

The following test below causes a random crash.   I am at a loss most of the time it works fine.

```
> @Test fun `perform login without a previously saved user`() =
> runBlocking {
>     testSavedUser1LiveData = MutableLiveData()
> 
>     coEvery { userDao.getCurrentUserLiveData() } returns testSavedUser1LiveData
>     coEvery { userDao.upsert(any()) } returns Unit
> 
>     coEvery { userAPIDataSource.fetchLoginUser(loginCredentials) } returns Unit
>     coEvery { userAPIDataSource.getLoginUserResults } returns testUser1ResponseLiveDataOfJsonElement
> 
>     loginRepository = LoginRepositoryImpl(userDao, companyDao, userAPIDataSource)
>     loginViewModel = LoginViewModel(dispatchers, validator, loginRepository)
> 
>     loginViewModel.loginLiveData().observeForever(loginLiveDataObserver)
>     loginViewModel.login(loginCredentials)
> 
>     coVerifyOrder {
>         loginLiveDataObserver.onChanged(enableLoading)
>         loginLiveDataObserver.onChanged(loginResults)
>         loginLiveDataObserver.onChanged(disableLoading)
>     } }
```

The code that accompanies this is
    fun login(credentials: LoginCredentials) {
        _loginLiveData.value = LoginResult.Loading(true)

```
    if(validator.validate(credentials)) {
        triggerLogin(credentials)
    } else {
        _loginLiveData.value = LoginResult.Failure("Incorrect Credentials")
        _loginLiveData.value = LoginResult.Loading(false)
    }
}

private fun triggerLogin(credentials: LoginCredentials) {
    launch(dispatchers.background) {
        loginRepository.performLogin(credentials)

        withContext(dispatchers.ui) {
            _loginLiveData.value = loginRepository.getLoginUserResults
            _loginLiveData.value = LoginResult.Loading(false)
        }
    }
}
```

the crash is:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: less calls happened
>   then demanded by order verification sequence.
>
> Matchers:  Observer(#94).onChanged(eq(Loading(value=true))))
>   Observer(#94).onChanged(eq(Success(user=Current User Response: 1:
>   testUserName1  )))) Observer(#94).onChanged(eq(Loading(value=false))))
>
> Calls: 1) Observer(#94).onChanged(Loading(value=true)) 2)
>   Observer(#94).onChanged(Success(user=Current User Response: 1:
>   testUserName1  ))
>
> Stack traces: 1)
>   io.mockk.impl.InternalPlatform.captureStackTrace
>   (InternalPlatform.kt:114)
>                                                                                    io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.handleInvocation
>   (MockKStub.kt:256)
>                                                  io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactoryHelper$mockHandler$1.invocation
>   (JvmMockFactoryHelper.kt:25)
>                                                                           io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.Interceptor.call
>   (Interceptor.kt:20)
>                                                                            io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.BaseAdvice.handle
>   (BaseAdvice.kt:42)
>                                                          io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.jvm.JvmMockKProxyInterceptor.interceptNoSuper
>   (JvmMockKProxyInterceptor.java:45)
>                                                                          androidx.lifecycle.Observer$Subclass18.onChanged
>   (-:-1)
>                                                                                     androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify
>   (LiveData.java:131)
>                                                                                     androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue
>   (LiveData.java:149)
>                                                                                     androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue
>   (LiveData.java:307)
>                                                                              androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue
>   (MutableLiveData.java:50)
>                                                                    com.test.testapp.ui.login.LoginViewModel.login
>   (LoginViewModel.kt:84)
>   com.test.testapp.featureTests.login.LoginFeatureShould$perform
>   login without a previously saved user$1.invokeSuspend
>   (LoginFeatureShould.kt:102)
>                                                             kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith
>   (ContinuationImpl.kt:32)
>                                                                               kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run
>   (Dispatched.kt:233)
>                                                                            kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent
>   (EventLoop.kt:116)
>                                                                            kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking
>   (Builders.kt:76)
>                                                                       kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking
>   (Builders.kt:53)
>                                                                                   kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking
>   (-:1)
>                                                                       kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default
>   (Builders.kt:35)
>                                                                                   kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default
>   (-:1)
>                                                      com.test.testapp.featureTests.login.LoginFeatureShould.perform
>   login without a previously saved user (LoginFeatureShould.kt:89)
>
> ```
>                                                                      sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0
> ```
>
> (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)N
>                                                                            sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
>   (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>                                                                        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
>   (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>                                                                                        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
>   (Method.java:498)
>                                                                 org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod
>   (ReflectionUtils.java:628)
>                                                            org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke
>   (ExecutableInvoker.java:117)
>                                                    org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7
>   (TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:184)
>                                               org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute
>   (ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>                                                    org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod
>   (TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:180)
>                                                    org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute
>   (TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:127)
>                                                    org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute
>   (TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
>                                                     org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5
>   (NodeTestTask.java:135)
>                                               org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute
>   (ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>                                                     org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7
>   (NodeTestTask.java:125)
>                                                             org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around
>   (Node.java:135)
>                                                     org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8
>   (NodeTestTask.java:123)
>                                               org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute
>   (ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>                                                     org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively
>   (NodeTestTask.java:122)
>                                                     org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute
>   (NodeTestTask.java:80)
>                                                                                             java.util.ArrayList.forEach
>   (ArrayList.java:1251)
>                        org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll
>   (SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
>                                                     org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5
>   (NodeTestTask.java:139)
>                                               org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute
>   (ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>                                                     org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7
>   (NodeTestTask.java:125)
>                                                             org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around
>   (Node.java:135)
>                                                     org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8
>   (NodeTestTask.java:123)
>                                               org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute
>   (ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>                                                     org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively
>   (NodeTestTask.java:122)
>                                                     org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute
>   (NodeTestTask.java:80)
>                                                                                             java.util.ArrayList.forEach
>   (ArrayList.java:1251)
>                        org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll
>   (SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
>                                                     org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5
>   (NodeTestTask.java:139)
>                                               org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute
>   (ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>                                                     org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7
>   (NodeTestTask.java:125)
>                                                             org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around
>   (Node.java:135)
>                                                     org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8
>   (NodeTestTask.java:123)
>                                               org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute
>   (ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>                                                     org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively
>   (NodeTestTask.java:122)
>                                                     org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute
>   (NodeTestTask.java:80)
>                        org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit
>   (SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
>                                         org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute
>   (HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
>                                           org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute
>   (HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
>                                                                org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute
>   (DefaultLauncher.java:229)
>                                                                org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6
>   (DefaultLauncher.java:197)
>                                                                org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams
>   (DefaultLauncher.java:211)
>                                                                org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute
>   (DefaultLauncher.java:191)
>                                                                org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute
>   (DefaultLauncher.java:128)
>                                                                        com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs
>   (JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
>                                                         com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs
>   (IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>                                                                    com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart
>   (JUnitStarter.java:242)
>                                                                    com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main
>   (JUnitStarter.java:70)
>
> 2)
>   io.mockk.impl.InternalPlatform.captureStackTrace
>   (InternalPlatform.kt:114)
>                                        io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.handleInvocation
>   (MockKStub.kt:256)
>   io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactoryHelper$mockHandler$1.invocation
>   (JvmMockFactoryHelper.kt:25)
>                               io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.Interceptor.call                      (Interceptor.kt:20)
>                                io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.BaseAdvice.handle
>   (BaseAdvice.kt:42)
>              io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.jvm.JvmMockKProxyInterceptor.interceptNoSuper
>   (JvmMockKProxyInterceptor.java:45)
>                              androidx.lifecycle.Observer$Subclass18.onChanged
>   (-:-1)
>                                         androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify
>   (LiveData.java:131)
>                                         androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue
>   (LiveData.java:149)
>                                         androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue
>   (LiveData.java:307)
>                                  androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue
>   (MutableLiveData.java:50)
>       com.test.testapp.ui.login.LoginViewModel$triggerLogin$1$1.invokeSuspend
>   (LoginViewModel.kt:99)
>       com.test.testapp.ui.login.LoginViewModel$triggerLogin$1$1.invoke
>   (LoginViewModel.kt:-1)
>                        kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn
>   (Undispatched.kt:91)
>                    kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext
>   (Builders.common.kt:146)
>                                       kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext               (-:1)
>
> ```
>   com.test.testapp.ui.login.LoginViewModel$triggerLogin$1.invokeSuspend
> ```
>
> (LoginViewModel.kt:98)
>                 kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith
>   (ContinuationImpl.kt:32)
>                                   kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run                       (Dispatched.kt:233)
>                    kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely
>   (CoroutineScheduler.kt:594)
>                    kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely
>   (CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
>             kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run                       (CoroutineScheduler.kt:742)
>
> at
>   io.mockk.impl.recording.states.VerifyingState.failIfNotPassed(VerifyingState.kt:66)
>     at
>   io.mockk.impl.recording.states.VerifyingState.recordingDone(VerifyingState.kt:42)
>     at
>   io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.done(CommonCallRecorder.kt:48)
>     at
>   io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator.record(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt:60)
>     at
>   io.mockk.impl.eval.VerifyBlockEvaluator.verify(VerifyBlockEvaluator.kt:27)
>     at io.mockk.MockKDsl.internalCoVerify(API.kt:143)   at
>   io.mockk.MockKDsl.internalCoVerify$default(API.kt:134)    at
>   io.mockk.MockKDsl.internalCoVerifyOrder(API.kt:212)   at
>   io.mockk.MockKKt.coVerifyOrder(MockK.kt:264)  at
>   io.mockk.MockKKt.coVerifyOrder$default(MockK.kt:261)  at
>   com.test.testapp.featureTests.login.LoginFeatureShould$perform
>   login without a previously saved
>   user$1.invokeSuspend(LoginFeatureShould.kt:104)   at
>   kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:32)
>     at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:233)     at
>   kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.kt:116)
>     at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:76)
>     at
>   kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:53)
>     at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)    at
>   kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:35)
>     at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
>     at com.test.testapp.featureTests.login.LoginFeatureShould.perform
>   login without a previously saved user(LoginFeatureShould.kt:89)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:628)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:117)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:184)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:180)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:127)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
>     at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1251)     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
>     at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1251)     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
>     at
>   com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Answer (score 0):

Check `timeout` feature in docs or on medium about advanced features(again link is on https://mockk.io)

Comment: Are you suggesting something like
        verify(timeout = 3000) { loginViewModel.login(loginCredentials) }

Comment: By adding that it causes it to crash every time

Comment: Try to submit github issue with all info for this case when you enable timeout